# Android: buffer.toString() dosen't work

Tags: android, buffer

I trying to connect my Android application to a database on remote host.
I want to use the records of the DB, but there's a problem when i try to do this:

```
if(buffer.toString()=="OPEN")
                    {
                        button_signal.setText("OPEN");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button_signal.setText("CLOSE");
                    }
```

I have checked buffer.toString() using Logs, and it is equal to "OPEN", but the button_signal's text is printed "CLOSE". Why? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare String with the "==" Operator in Java. A String is an Object.
Try this buffer.toString().equals("OPEN");

EDIT:

Even better is if you compare it like this: "OPEN".equals(buffer.toString())

Because it won't throw an exception if buffer is null.

Comment: "It won't throw an exception if buffer is null." It will because `buffer.toString()` will throw :) Apart from that, the `"string".equals(stuffOrNull)` schema is indeed the better one.

Comment: Thank you all, guys. Now it works! What a stupid errore that i made!

Answer (score 2):

It might have some invisible characters or some letters might be in different case, so please try this:

```
buffer.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("OPEN");
```